# Почему обнуляется переданный в поток указатель? CreateThread

Tags: c++, windows, многопоточность, winapi, указатели

Здравствуйте! 
У меня есть 2 глобальных массива `static TCHAR abc[32+1];` и  `static TCHAR defa[32+1];`, объявлены в главном cpp, сразу после includ-ов.

Есть главная ф-ия, которая в свою очередь запускает функцию start():

```
//Main.cpp
    void WINAPI entryPoint() {
      start();
      while (true) { Sleep(3000); MessageBox(0,abc,0,0);} 
    }
```

Функция start заполняет массив определенным содержанием, а дальше запускает ф-ию(startThread), которая находится уже в другом файле cpp, которая в свою очередь запускает поток с помощью CreateThread:

```
//Main.cpp
    bool start() {
       lstrcpy(abc, _T("Hello")); 
       lstrcpy(defa, _T("How are you?"));
       startThread(abc);
       MessageBox(0,_T("Завершить функцию start?"));
    }

//Thread.cpp
struct PARAMS{
    TCHAR *abc;
    TCHAR *defa;
}

    void startThread(TCHAR *abc, TCHAR *defa) {
        PARAMS arr = { abc, defa };
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &threadfunction, &arr, 0, NULL);

    }
```

Сама функция потока выглядит так:

```
//Thread.cpp
    DWORD WINAPI threadfunction(LPVOID arr) {
        PARAMS*PARR= (PARAMS*)arr;
       while (true) {
            MessageBox(0, PARR->abc, L"Thread 2", 0);
            MessageBox(0, PARR->defa, L"Thread 2", 0);
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что после того как завершается функция bool start() в главном потоке, из abc и defa исчезают значения и поток начинает выдавать пустые сообщения, я не понимаю почему это происходит. При чем, если не завершать функцию start(), т.е. не закрывать мессагу  `MessageBox(0,_T("Завершить функцию start?"));`, то все нормально. Из главного потока я по прежнему имею доступ к этим переменным, даже после завершения start(), т.е. вот тут все нормально продолжает работать `while (true) { Sleep(3000); MessageBox(0,abc,0,0);}`

Реализация на чистом WinApi, так что, другие варианты создания потоков не рассматриваю.

Answer (score 5):

```
void startThread(TCHAR *abc, TCHAR *defa) {
    PARAMS arr = { abc, defa };
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, &threadfunction, &arr, 0, NULL);

}
```

В любом случае передавать в функцию потока адрес локального объекта `arr` - очень нехорошо. Поток еще и запуститься как следует не успевает, а выделенная под `arr` память уже недействительна...

Comment: Как можно поступить, чтобы было правильно? P.s. Кажется начинаю понимать, проблема не в массивах, а в arr. Он то не глобальный, точно!

Comment: Ну, как угодно, лишь бы время его жизни было достаточно большим. Например, глобальная переменная, статическая переменная функции - но это чревато лишними связями и иже с ними, типа отсутствия реентерабельности. Еще вариант - создать в динамической памяти, которую потом освободить (уже в потоке).

Comment: Объявил _static PARAMS arr;_  глобально, а в _startThread_ делаю только заполнение: _arr = { abc, defa };_. Теперь работает, но волнует вопрос, не черевато ли это последствиями?

Comment: Чревато, пожалуй, только тем, что он становится ресурсом :) - например, если идет несколько вызовов с разными значениями (т.е. в один передаете `abc`, в другой - еще что-то) - то может оказаться так, что вы меняете эту структуру до того, как ею воспользуется поток, в который она передана. Ну, и глобальные переменные - это вообще всегда не слишком хорошо...

Answer (score 1):

после "PARAMS arr = { abc, defa };
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &threadfunction, &arr, 0, NULL);"
надо подключиться к потоку и дождаться его завершения или PARAMS на new и освобождать внутри потока.

Comment: Поток должен работать до конца работы программы, т.е. он не завершится(там бесконечный цикл). Темболее, если я буду ждать завершения работы второго потока, у меня на этом ожидании встанет основной поток, а мне надо чтобы они вместе работали.

Comment: тогда new, а далее share_pointer, или конструктор переноса... Но что это:  lstrcpy(abc, _T("Hello")); 
       lstrcpy(defa, _T("How are you?"));
       startThread(abc);

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
void startThread(TCHAR *abc, TCHAR *defa) {
    PARAMS arr = new PARAMS{ abc, defa };
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, &threadfunction, arr, 0, NULL);
}
```

И вызывать деструктор в функции потока. Еще лучше сделать так:

```
void startThread(TCHAR *abc, TCHAR *defa) {
  std::thread thread{ [abs, defa]{
    while (true) {
      MessageBox(0, abc, L"Thread 2", 0);
      MessageBox(0, defa, L"Thread 2", 0); 
    }
    // delete[] abs; deletee[] defa; 
    // Кто-то должен освобождать память, но цикл бесконечный.
  }};
  thread.detach(); // Отпускаем поток в свободное плаванье. Ну или ждем завершения при помощи thread.join();
}
```

Кроме того, по хорошему нужно завершить поток до завершения программы, т.к. иначе не все деструкторы будут вызваны. Ресурсы система, конечно, освободит, но в реальных проектах может потребоваться выполнить дополнительные действия, например, запись в log файлы. Для этого можно использовать механизм событий, или банально общие атомарные переменные (посмотрите в сторону `std::atomic<bool>`). Тогда вместо `while(true)` будет `while(cond)`, и после завершения цикла можно освобождать ресурсы и совершать другие действия.